# How to load multiple images in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I need to load around 200 images in pygame to be blitted at various points in my game. I tried writing a function for this but kept coming back with `NameError: name 'tomato' is not defined`.

All of the image names are what the variable of the loaded image is stored under: `tomato = pygame.image.load("tomato.png")`

Would using an array be better, if so how would I do that?

The code:

```
def load(image):
    imagename = image
    imagetitle = str(imagename)+".png"
    image = pygame.image.load(imagetitle)
    return image

load("tomato")

def blit_f(fruit):
    gamedisplay.blit(fruit,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()

fruitlist = []        

running = False
while not running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            color = screen.get_at(mouse)

            if color == (209,0,0,255):
                blit_f(tomato)
                fruitlist.insert(0,"tomato")

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            if fruitlist[0] == "tomato":
                gamedisplay.blit(tomato,(0,0))
                pygame.display.update()
```

The NameError occurs only when the condition leading to the blitting of `tomato.png` is met: when I hover over the tomato image i.e. color red

If I write `load(tomato)` instead of with `""`, NameError comes up as soon as I run the code, and highlights `load(tomato)` instead of `gamedisplay.blit(tomato)` as for with `load("tomato")`.

Comment: where is your code showing that you try to use tomato before defining it?

Comment: check order of operations in your code

Comment: Edit your original question with the code you're using to cause this error @I.Kaur

Comment: The function had parameter load(image) and load(tomato) came after the function. The error highlighted a later line: gamedisplay.blit(tomato)

Comment: Show *all* of your code, the problem is `tomato` isn't defined at the time of you calling `load(tomato)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load so many images, use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) and put all the images in the directory into a dictionary. Also, use `convert` or `convert_alpha` after loading the images to improve the performance.

```
def load_images(path_to_directory):
    """Load images and return them as a dict."""
    image_dict = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(path_to_directory):
        if filename.endswith('.png'):
            path = os.path.join(path_to_directory, filename)
            key = filename[:-4]
            image_dict[key] = pygame.image.load(path).convert()
    return image_dict
```

If you want to load all images from subdirectories as well, use `os.walk`:

```
def load_images(path_to_directory):
    """Load all images from subdirectories and return them as a dict."""
    images = {}
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path_to_directory):
        for name in filenames:
            if name.endswith('.png'):
                key = name[:-4]
                img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(dirpath, name)).convert()
                images[key] = img
    return images
```

Comment: How can I load many images from 7 sub files that are in a file?

Comment: Do you mean you want to load all images in 7 subdirectories? Then you can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) or use the function that I showed you above several times (then you would get 7 different dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

You do load the image by calling `load("tomato")`, but you ignore the return value. Try

```
tomato = load("tomato")
```

instead.

Comment: I kept the function as is and used this line, and it worked - doing this for 199 more images is a little less tedious than before, thanks!