# image.load from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to use a list to randomly pick an image but I got this error:

> mob =
>   random(list[pygame.image.load("image1.png"),pygame.image.load("image2.png"),pygame.image.load("image3.png"),])
>   TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

If I load the image manually in the pygame.image.load("Image") it works, but then I got this error. angryball_image_rect should be defined tho

> screen.blit(angryball, angryball_image_rect.move(angryball_image_rect.width, 0))
>   NameError: name 'angryball_image_rect' is not defined

```
import pygame
import os
import random

size = width, height = 750, 422
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

img_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd())
background_image = pygame.image.load('background.jpg').convert()
bg_image_rect = background_image.get_rect()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)

pygame.display.set_caption("BallGame")

class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
        self.image_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image_rect.x
        self.image_rect.y
        self.facing = 'LEFT'

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and self.image_rect.y < 321:
            self.facing = 'DOWN'
            self.image_rect.y += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_UP] and self.image_rect.y > 0:
                self.facing = 'UP'
        self.image_rect.y -= dist
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.image_rect.x < 649:
           self.facing = 'RIGHT'
            self.image_rect.x += dist
       elif key[pygame.K_LEFT] and self.image_rect.x > 0:
            self.facing = 'LEFT'
            self.image_rect.x -= dist

    def draw(self, surface):
        if self.facing == "RIGHT":
            surface.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False),(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))
        elif self.facing == "DOWN":
            surface.blit(pygame.image.load("ball_down.png"),(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))
        if self.facing == "UP":
            surface.blit(pygame.image.load("ball_up.png"),(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))
        elif self.facing == "LEFT":
            surface.blit(self.image,(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))


#List of objects to randomly select the image of the Angryball
mob = random(list[pygame.image.load("image1.png"),pygame.image.load("image2.png"),pygame.image.load("image3.png"),])

class Angryball(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = mob
        self.image_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image_rect.x
        self.image_rect.y
        self.facing = 'LEFT'


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((750, 422))

ball = Ball()
angryball = Angryball()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.music.load("bg_music.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

running = True
while running:
    esc_key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if esc_key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            running = False

    ball.handle_keys()

#Move the Angryball from right to left at speed 5 spawning randomly on the right border when it reaches the left border
    screen.blit(angryball, angryball_image_rect.move(angryball_image_rect.width, 0))
    angryball_image_rect = angryball.get_rect()
    angryball_image_rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
    if angryball_image_rect.x <= 0:
        angryball_image_rect.x = random.randint(101, 649) #101 is the size of the image so it wont be split at the border's edge

    screen.blit(background_image, bg_image_rect)
    screen.blit(background_image, bg_image_rect.move(bg_image_rect.width, 0))
    bg_image_rect.move_ip(-2, 0)
    if bg_image_rect.right <= 0:
        bg_image_rect.x = 0


    ball.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: @skrx I'm seeking guidance because i'm still learning and the only things i have "clear" are the steps i have to make. I am stuck because i don't know where to start so some quick hints will be great to make my mind clear. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @skrx For example, i've found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732487/how-to-load-multiple-images-in-pygame as a possible solution for the first point but i thought it could be possibile to use the random function directly in a pygame.image.load() by loading a list of objects

Comment: Okay, to spawn the sprites, first load the images before the game loop starts and put them into a list, then in your main loop generate some random coordinates at the side of the screen with the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module and finally create instances of your sprite, pass a random image and the coordinates and add the sprites to a pygame sprite group or list.

Comment: @skrx Thank you

Comment: For the movement it would be a good idea to give your sprite class an `update` method in which you update the position of the sprite each frame. In the main loop iterate over your sprite container with a `for` loop and call the `update` method of the sprites to move them. With a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) you can just call `my_sprite_group.update()`.  -- Try to implement these things and edit your question if you got a more specific problem. I could also create a chat room.

Comment: @skrx Edited with my attemps

Answer (score 1):

Define your images list in the global scope and fill it with your images. Then you can call [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to get one of the images in the list and pass it together with your random coordinates to the `__init__` method of your sprite class where you can assign them to the specific attributes of the sprite.

```
# Load the images once and put them into a global list. Then you don't have
# to load them from the hard disk again (which is inefficient) and you can
# use `random.choice` to pick one of the images. Also, call convert or
# convert_alpha to improve the blit performance.
mob_images = [
    pygame.image.load("image1.png").convert_alpha(),
    pygame.image.load("image2.png").convert_alpha(),
    pygame.image.load("image3.png").convert_alpha(),
    ]

mob_image = random.choice(mob_images)  # Pick a random image.


class Angryball(object):
    # The __init__ method now takes an image (pygame.Surface) and
    # the x- and y-position.
    def __init__(self, image, pos_x, pos_y):
        self.image = image
        self.image_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image_rect.x = pos_x
        self.image_rect.y = pos_y
        self.facing = 'LEFT'

# Pass the random image and the coordinates to the `__init__` method.
angryball = Angryball(mob_image, 700, random.randrange(400))
```

---

The `TypeError` was raised because you tried to call `list` with square brackets (which are used for indexing):

```
list[1, 2, 3]  # Won't work, because square brackets are used for indexing.

list([1, 2, 3])  # This works but is unnecessary, because it's already a list.
```

Comment: Thank you for your support and explanations, i will open another topic for the spawning part :)